# DB2 - Sorting alphabiatically

Tags: db2

I have a DB2 database that I am trying to sort by Alphabetical order. The problem is, db2 doesn't seem to consider A=a during sorting, thus I get results like this:

A B C T a b c g

I want to get:

A a b B C c g T

What special  thing needs to be done that I don't know about?

In SQL, we have COLLATE NOCASE ASC. Can anyone plz tell me what is ab alternative for this in db2.

Comment: Not familiar with DB2, but in Oracle SQL, I would do something like select * from city order by upper(CITY_NAME); Where upper is an intrinsic function that converts all lower case characters to upper case. Since it is only on the order by it does not affect what is returned.

Comment: `In **SQL**, we have COLLATE NOCASE ASC.` Are you using SQL to access your DB2 database? What DB2 version? What platform is it installed on?

Comment: No I m nt using SQL.Instead I am using DB2 9.5

Comment: `SQL` is a language, not a product. I'm guessing you mean `SQL Server`.

Comment: As noted by @bhamby , **SQL** is a language. It is used to query SQL-compliant databases created in DBMSs such as DB2, Oracle, SQL Server and others. I'm not aware of `COLLATE NOCASE ASC` being part of standard SQL. (I think it's available in SQLite.) There are various ways to manipulate columns as case-insensitive in DB2 9.5. Which way could depend on table volumes, number of queries and perhaps stage of development and other factors. Is this a new table you can recreate?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one-time problem (i.e. with one single query), then the solution that @Paul Stearns recommends (using `UPPER()`) will function.

However, if this is an issue that will affect all queries in your application, you should consider what the proper [collating sequence](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/c0006812.html) should be for your database.  The default collating sequence sorts based on the code point, which is why you are seeing the sort order you see.

Unfortunately you can't change the collating sequence for a database;  it's set when the database is created.  So once you have decided what the correct collating sequence is, you'll need to create a new database and copy the data from the existing database to the new database.

Doing this may be a pain (especially if you have a very large database), but it will save you a lot of headaches (and performance issues that would arise from relying on `UPPER()` a lot of the time) in the future.